# Android build failed with cordova release

Tags: android, cordova, android-proguard

My Android build is getting failed when I am running `cordova build --release android -debug` command. I am able to generate normal build. I am using cordova v7.0.0

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 39.667 secs

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: E:\Worklight Mobile App\MFP8.0\mfp-ws\2FileUI\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\file\AssetFilesystem.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: there were 7 duplicate class definitions.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
Warning: okhttp3.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced method 'long getContentLengthLong()' in library class java.net.HttpURLConnection
Warning: okhttp3.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced method 'long getHeaderFieldLong(java.lang.String,long)' in library class java.net.HttpURLConnection
Warning: okhttp3.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: okhttp3.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: okhttp3.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: okhttp3.internal.huc.OkHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: okhttp3.internal.huc.OkHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: okhttp3.internal.huc.OkHttpsURLConnection: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning: there were 6 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added below lines in proguard file and the error went away:

```
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.huc.**
```